# MongoDB date object returns EDT when converted to string

Tags: javascript, date, mongodb, object

I'm have a date field in MongoDB which returns an object in GMT that looks like this.

`Fri, 20 Apr 2012 22:13:30 GMT`

When I convert this to string (which is in Handlebar.js templates) it's changed to:

`Fri Apr 20 2012 18:13:30 GMT-0400 (EDT)`

This obviously won't work.  Any ideas how to maintain the GMT when this is converted to a string?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Does the .toGMTString() method return the desired result?

```
> now = new Date()
ISODate("2012-04-19T20:36:12.817Z")
> now.toGMTString()
Thu, 19 Apr 2012 20:36:12 GMT
>
```

Hopefully the answer is as simple as that.  Let me know if I have misunderstood your question!

Comment: Well, it still converts to the local timezone, I think the question is can a date maintain itself as an object, when rendering through Handlebars

Comment: Aha.  Sorry.  As I said, I was afraid that I might have misunderstood your question.  My above example was done with the Mongo JS shell.  Unfortunately, I am not familiar with Handlebars.  Hopefully another member of the community will be able to provide a better answer.